# Oauth2 SSO Flow

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, single-sign-on, openid

I have a `SpringBoot 2.3.4` small application to test the `SSO Authentication` procedure to several Provider, Open ID compatible, as *Okta*, *Google*, *Github* ecc..

It's pretty simple and everything works fine but I implement the login page with `Thymeleaf 3` and now I want to switch to `Angular 11` (or to a fully REST service).

The problem is that the Authentication flow starts with this Form action call:

```
<form method="get" th:action="@{/oauth2/authorization/{clientId}}">
  <button id="login-button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

To reply this call manually (maybe if I can't use an html form) I do a simple redirect as follow:

```
return "redirect:http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/okta";
```

Is there a more elegant way to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Okta's spring boot starter SDK to make it easier: https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot

For the angular JS front end, you can use Okta's Angular JS SDK: https://github.com/okta/okta-angular